# Adding a text box in Android Studo

Tags: android-studio

Trying to use AndroidStudio (3.4.2) for the first time and it appers to be substantially different to the tutorial at
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui

For example:

- There is no *layout editor toolbar* let alone a *show* button.
- There is no *autoconnect* button
- It doesn't show any wiggly lines from the middle of the blue square to its edges.
- When adding a text box it goes to the top left and can't be moved.

WTF is going on? This is awful!

[image]

Comment: You're likely not seeing the squiggly lines because your activity_main has a layout other than a constraint layout on it

Answer (score 2):

So I know this may sound like the hard answer, but in the long run it will make life 1000x easier.
You need to learn XML to design the activities. It's fairly simple and really easy to research. The reason the textbox can't be moved is because the default layout is ConstraintLayout. In order to fix this, go to the xml file and change the Constraint layout to either Relative layout or Linear Layout. In the end, its more simple to learn straight xml.

Comment: I found the XML and it looks pretty awful -- as XML usually does.

Deleted it all with the intention of starting from scratch but that's just completely broken it.

Comment: http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/allalaadimised/reading/Android-UI-Design.pdf     Try this tutorial

Comment: However, I have now managed to do *something*!

With a *linear layout* is it possible to put space between controls?

Comment: Yes! You can use layout margins and padding. Here is a tutorial to help with that: http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn Android programming from [here](https://www.udemy.com/learn-android-application-development-y/) or somewhere else because the Android documentation can be confusing especially for a beginner like yourself and trust me, I've been there.

Comment: Anything written down? I don't really do videos.

Comment: It's something you'd have to do but I'll try and find a tutorial without videos for you

Comment: I found this [this](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/) and [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3340234/tutorial-series-android-studio-for-beginners.html) it's the best I could do and if you don't like it you could try googling for tutorials.